# Haskell data Nat

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Below is from Programming in Haskell by Hutton (p. 102).

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

natToInt :: Nat -> Int
natToInt Zero = 0
natToInt (Succ n) = 1 + natToInt n
```

If I type `natToInt Zero` in ghci, I get 0. If I type `natToInt (Succ Zero)`, I get 1.

But `natToInt (Succ (Succ Zero))` returns 2. I understand it logically but I do not understand how it works recursively inside this statement.

Doesn't the inner `(Succ Zero)` return 1? That means, in my opinion, outermost takes 1 as argument Which is not correct since 1 is not of type Nat. 
Then it would be

`natToInt (Succ ( 1 + 0))`.

Can someone please help me understand it?

Comment: think of as unwrapping `Succ`s from outer to inner.

Comment: No, `natToInt (Succ Zero)` returns 1. `Succ Zero` itself returns a value of type `Nat`.

Answer (score 8):

you have a small mistake in the replacement - you do replace the wrong `Succ` here.

let's do it step by step:

```
natToInt (Succ (Succ Zero))
{ case 2: (Succ n) = Succ (Succ Zero) so n = Succ Zero}
= 1 + natToInt (Succ Zero)
{ case 2: (Succ n) = Succ Zero so n = Zero}
= 1 + (1 + natToInt Zero)
{ case 1}
= 1 + (1 + 0)
= 1 + 1
= 2
```

see: you just have to replace/match expressions on both sides

Comment: Is the outer Succ executed first then?

Comment: @MaxKim: Yes. You're always only looking at the shell. If you want to get at the innards, you have to do so explicitly.